# sort -c output being redirected to a file: Linux command

Tags: linux, shell

Why is `sort -c` output not being redirected to file `temp.txt`?
If I remove `-c`, it *does* redirect, as seen below:

```
$ cat numericSort
33:Thirty Three:6
11:Eleven:2
45:Forty Five:9
01:Zero One:1
99:Ninety Nine:9
18:Eighteen:01
56:Fifty Six:4
78:Seventy Eight:2


$ sort numericSort > temp.txt


$ cat temp.txt
01:Zero One:1
11:Eleven:2
18:Eighteen:01
33:Thirty Three:6
45:Forty Five:9
56:Fifty Six:4
78:Seventy Eight:2
99:Ninety Nine:9


$ rm temp.txt


$ sort -c numericSort > temp.txt
sort: numericSort:2: disorder: 11:Eleven:2


$ cat temp.txt
# No Output Here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `sort -c` goes to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

If you want to redirect that instead:

```
$ sort -c numericSort 2> temp.txt
```

Comment: +1; it should be noted that POSIX specifies that NO output be produced  with `-c` ("No output shall be produced; only the exit code shall be affected." - http://man.cx/sort), so the `stderr` output that (at least) GNU `sort` and BSD `sort` produce in case the input is NOT sorted is a non-POSIX extension.

Answer (score 3):

Based on document of `sort` command

> -c, --check, --check=diagnose-first
>
> ```
>           check for sorted input; do not sort
> ```
>
> Check whether the given files are already sorted: if  they  are not
>   all sorted, print an **error message** and exit with a status of 1.

so your command `sort -c numericSort > temp.txt` is essentially just checking whether the file `numericSort` is sorted or not. If not sorted print error on `STDERR` and hence you don't see any output to `temp.txt`. Probably you want to redirect STDERR instead like

```
sort -c numericSort 2> temp.txt
```